# Why do I get a conversion error for Blank in the Integer location in H2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

In H2 on spring, Blank is not allowed and I get an error "Data conversion error converting".

It seems that this error occurs when the type is set to Integer.

#### environment

・spring (STS)

#### screenshot

[H2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMlb.png)

[STS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ObCF.png)

Comment: Beside the error: why are you using `@NotBlank` for an Integer? Instead of using `@NotNull`? (Quote from the [docs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html) for `NotBlank`: "Accepts CharSequence.")

Comment: Please don't post code as a screenshot but rather just as code. Even worse put a link to a screenshot with code, so people wanting to help need to navigate away from your question.